# Does SQLite data retain after replace the app

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update my appliaction from an external URL. 
If there is any change in the version file on the specific URL , the application checks for it and starts downloading the latest uploaded APK from url.

After downloading the application the new apk starts installing and says it will replace the existing app in the phone.

My question : In this scenario, the complete database containing the data of the previous app gets cleared or not ?

Comment: Why are you confused? Didn't you look at the database? Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and have you declared the database version correctly?

Comment: ya I m using the SQLiteOpenHelper and in all my versions of the application I have kept the same version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an app is upgraded, any data files created by the app are not affected.

When `SQLiteOpenHelper` detects that the database file's version is smaller than the version declared by your app, it calls `onUpgrade`.

Comment: The tables in the database of the new application are modified in the coding .Hence , to reflect them in the user's phone I need to set the new version to the database and call the drop and create query in the upgrade method.

Comment: Hey thanks I set the updated version as 2 , as the previous version was 1 , Inside Upgrade method I called drop and create query and then all set. Thanks @CL